# What does 'result' in ExecutorService.submit(Runnable task, T result) do?

Tags: java, synchronization

Looking at the javadocs it just says

> `<T> Future<T> submit(Runnable task, T result)`
>
> Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future representing that task. The Future's get method will return the given result upon successful completion.
>
> Parameters:
>
> task - the task to submit
>
> result - the result to return

but what does it do with result? does it store anything there? does it just use the type of result to specify the type of `Future<T>`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't do anything with the result - just holds it. When the task successfully completes, calling `future.get()` will return the result you passed in.

Here is the source code of Executors$RunnableAdapter, which shows that after the task has run, the original result is returned:

```
static final class RunnableAdapter<T> implements Callable<T> {
    final Runnable task;
    final T result;
    RunnableAdapter(Runnable  task, T result) {
        this.task = task;
        this.result = result;
    }
    public T call() {
        task.run();
        return result;
    }
}
```

And yes, the generic type of the result should match that of the returned Future.

Comment: Furthermore, from the `FutureTask` constructor api:  "result - the result to return on successful completion. If you don't need a particular result, consider using constructions of the form: Future<?> f = new FutureTask<Object>(runnable, null)"

Comment: i am curious where this might be useful

Answer (score 11):

Runnable does not return anything and Future must return something so this method allows you to predefine the result of the returned future.

If you don't want to return a thing you can return null and I think the `Void` type exists to express that kind of things.

```
Future<Void> myFuture = executor.submit(myTask, null);
```

You know `myFuture.get()` will return `null` in this case but only after the task has been run, so you would use it to wait and throw any exception that were thrown in the task.

```
try {
  myFuture.get();
  // After task is executed successfully
  ...
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  Throwable c = e.getCause();
  log.error("Something happened running task", c);
  // After task is aborted by exception
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can mutate the object that was passed-in during the task.  For example:

```
final String[] mutable = new String[1];
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mutable[0] = "howdy";
    }
};
Future<String[]> f = executorService.submit(r, mutable);
String[] result = f.get();
System.out.println("result[0]: " + result[0]);
```

When I run this code it outputs:

```
result[0]: howdy
```

Comment: This answer shows something interesting but the code to show it is not correct. depending on the executorService class used the task may run in a different thread (probably will) and the mutable array might be cached and show memory consistency error between threads. You should synchronize or use an `AtomicReference<String>` instead. Also you can submit a `Callable<String>` instead of a Runnable if you want to get a result.