# Getting Future with correct type from ExecutorService using SwingWorker runnables

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, executorservice, swingworker

I want to submit some SwingWorkers to ExecutorService, and get Futures from them to see later if they have finished and what the results are.

However, ExecutorService's submit method will only return a `Future<?>` when I want a `Future<Integer>`.

So, questions:

- Am I extending SwingWorker correctly? The first generic type is what is returned by get() on the SwingWorker, so I guessed it is also what the Future get() method will return.
- Is SwingWorker the wrong thing to use? (Trying to read about this problem, I see mostly people submitting Callables to ExecutorService) If so, what would be better and what is the best way to convert it? (my actual extension of SwingWorker is more complex than this example, and updates the GUI etc). I started trying to implement Callable in a new class but I am not sure how to implement the publish/process process (no pun intended).

Some example code that reproduces the problem:

The SwingWorker extension

```
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Void>
{
    public Worker ()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public Integer doInBackground()
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void done()
    {
        System.out.println("done\n");
    }
}
```

Main - the `executor.submit(w)` part gives a compile error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Future<capture#1-of ?> to Future<Integer>
```

And asks if I'd like to change future to be of type `Future<?>` or cast the `executor.submit(w)` part to `Future<Integer>`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        Worker w = new Worker();
        Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(w);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use this variation of [`submit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-T-) to make the result type explicit:

```
<T> Future<T> submit(Runnable task, T result)
```

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6456504/230513), `submit()` doesn't do anything with `result`. "When the task successfully completes, calling `future.get()` will return the result you passed in." Note that the type of `result` matches that of the [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) result type, `T`.

Code:

```
Integer i = 42;
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(w, i);
System.out.println(future.get());
```

Console:

```
42
done
```

In the larger context of your actual program, you'll want to `publish()` intermediate results and `process()` them on the EDT.

Comment: Does this mean that it isn't possible to retrieve the result of SwingWorker's doInBackground()?

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise SwingWorker has a Future itself. So now I'm going to do executor.execute(w) and put all the w's in a map to look at them later. If anyone is wondering how SwingWorker actually works I found the source code here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/SwingWorker.java#SwingWorker

Comment: Glad it helped. I would say `SwingWorker` _is a_ `Future<T>`, as well as a `Runnable`, and `RunnableFuture<T>`. See also [*Waiting for multiple SwingWorkers*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513).